# Gatsby js files are gzipped only on localhost dev, but not on s3 production

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, gatsby

Gatsby js files are gzipped only on localhost dev, but not on s3 production

Is this normal or am i doing something wrong?
If yes, how can i gzip my files?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your hosting provider.
I used aws s3 and cloudfront, and compression is not to be done by gatsby but by hosting provider and cloudfront provides compression by default, but in my case, i had cache policy disabled (and compression with it automatically as well) because of high TTL problem i faced before.
So i created custom cache policy with cache enabled and lower TTL.

But if you need to compress files on build time, you can use gatsby-plugin-brotli and gatsby-plugin-zopfli.